# Sammy.js intercepts all click events

Tags: sammy.js

I am using knockout and sammy together. I have a mobile page where i declared

```
$.sammy('#portal', function(){.....}).
```

outside '#portal' I have a regular anchor

```
<a href="otherpage.html">friends</a>.
```

The issue is that when i click the anchor the url is updated but the page stays at the original page where i have sammy loaded....I thought that sammy will only trigger if the event was coming from '#portal'. Does someone knows why the page is being locked and not redirecting?

Comment: If you put breakpoints in your route handlers and then click on other otherpage.html, do the break points get hit? are you sure sammy is handling the link?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `'/'` instead of `''` for your sammy default route.